# Positioning in CSS regarding menus

Tags: html, css, css-position

If you look at the code provided below there are a few positioning issues. Mainly I need to make it such that the slide menu opens from under the open button and **does not push the image out of the way**. Furthermore, I need the open buttons to be next to each other, but a little more spread out. I'm not so great at positioning and any other tips would be really appreciated, Thanks!

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #592881
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(89, 40, 129, .7);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: static;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 140px;
    max-height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    color: #A8A8A8;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

.overlay {
    float:left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Masters of Engineering</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\Coding\Robotics Site\css\Main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Corner Logo.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Bar"></div>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
    </script>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block;" onmouseenter="openNav()" onmouseleave="closeNav()">&#9776;open</span>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block;" onmouseenter="openNav()" onmouseleave="closeNav()">&#9776;open</span>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slideshow'>
        <div class="slides">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" height="auto" width="auto">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/Wallpaper-Images/Wallpaper-Images-005.jpg" height=auto width=auto>
            <img class="mySlides fade" src='https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a012000/a012005/Swift_Tidal_Disruption_2_Still.jpg' height="auto" width="auto">
        </div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer); 
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10094;
            </a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10095;
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    var myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
        x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    myTimer; //change image every 3.5 seconds
    </script>
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        <img src='http://www.mastersny.org/uploaded/template/default/images/common/bottom-logo.png'>
        <p>49 Clinton Avenue</p>
        <p>Dobbs Ferry, NY 10522</p>
        <p>(914) 479-6400</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a div container and moves the 2nd spans into it with a position of absolute. Added some margins, removes an extra closing div at the bottom, and you need to put an alt on your images. Hope it helps.

Here is your CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Bar {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 64px;
background-color: #592881
}

#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 100px;
left: 0;
background: rgba(89, 40, 129, .7);
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;
text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: black;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
position: static;
}

.sidenav a:hover {color: gray;}

.sidenav .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 25px;
font-size: 36px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
.sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
.sidenav a {
font-size: 18px;
}}

.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% {-webkit-opacity: .4;
opacity: .4;
}
100% {-webkit-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}}

@keyframes fade {
0%  {
-webkit-opacity: .4;
opacity: .4;
}
100%  {
-webkit-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}}

.container {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.slides {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
display: block;
left: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 100%;    
padding-top: 140px;
max-height: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
float: right;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
left: 0px;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}
.footer {
position: relative;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
color: #A8A8A8;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 400px;
}

.overlay {
float:left;
height: 70%;
width: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: .5s;
}
.overlay-content {
position: relative;
top: 25%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.overlay a {
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 36px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {color: #f1f1f1;}
.overlay .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 45px;
font-size: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
.overlay a {font-size: 20px}
.overlay .closebtn {
font-size: 40px;
top: 15px;
right: 35px;
}}
.buttonContainer{
height:3em;
width:100%;
background-color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Masters of Engineering</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Zach/Desktop/Coding/Robotics%20Site/css/Main.css">
<link rel="icon" href="img/Corner Logo.ico">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>append your style here....</style>
<script>
function openNav() {   document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%"; }
function closeNav() {document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Bar"></div>
<div class="buttonContainer">  
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block; position:absolute;" onmouseover="openNav();" onmouseout="closeNav();">&#9776;open</span>
<span style="margin-left:10%;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; position:relative; display: inline-block;" onmouseover="openNav();" onmouseout="closeNav();">&#9776;open</span>
</div>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseover="openNav();" onmouseout="closeNav();">
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a></div></div>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseover="openNav();" onmouseout="closeNav();">
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a></div></div>
<div class='slideshow'>
<div class="slides">
<img class="mySlides fade" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" height="auto" width="auto">
<img class="mySlides fade" src="https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/Wallpaper-Images/Wallpaper-Images-005.jpg" height=auto width=auto>
<img class="mySlides fade" src='https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a012000/a012005/Swift_Tidal_Disruption_2_Still.jpg' height="auto" width="auto">
</div>
<div class='buttons'>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1); 
clearInterval(myTimer); 
myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10094;
</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1); 
clearInterval(myTimer);
myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10095;
</a>
</div>
</div>


<script>
var myIndex = 0;
var myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);
carousel();
function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
}
myTimer; //change image every 3.5 seconds
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) { showDivs(slideIndex += n);}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";
}
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
}
</script>
<div class='footer'>
<img src='http://www.mastersny.org/uploaded/template/default/images/common/bottom-logo.png'>
<p>49 Clinton Avenue</p>
<p>Dobbs Ferry, NY 10522</p>
<p>(914) 479-6400</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set position: absolute for the slide menu and margin-right for the first menu button :)

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #592881
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(89, 40, 129, .7);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: static;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 140px;
    max-height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    color: #A8A8A8;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 115px;
    float:left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Masters of Engineering</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\Coding\Robotics Site\css\Main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Corner Logo.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Bar"></div>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
    </script>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block; margin-right: 15px" onmouseenter="openNav()" onmouseleave="closeNav()">&#9776;open</span>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block;" onmouseenter="openNav()" onmouseleave="closeNav()">&#9776;open</span>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slideshow'>
        <div class="slides">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" height="auto" width="auto">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/Wallpaper-Images/Wallpaper-Images-005.jpg" height=auto width=auto>
            <img class="mySlides fade" src='https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a012000/a012005/Swift_Tidal_Disruption_2_Still.jpg' height="auto" width="auto">
        </div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer); 
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10094;
            </a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10095;
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    var myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
        x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    myTimer; //change image every 3.5 seconds
    </script>
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        <img src='http://www.mastersny.org/uploaded/template/default/images/common/bottom-logo.png'>
        <p>49 Clinton Avenue</p>
        <p>Dobbs Ferry, NY 10522</p>
        <p>(914) 479-6400</p>
    </div>
</body>
```